# ERROR when combining 2 String[][] and 1 String[] become one String[][]

Tags: java, arrays

needs help on my problem, I need to combine 3 array into one multidimensional array. but I always encounter error which some value return null. the data in first array (String[][]dataset) was:

```
001200700001        70        70        70        55        70        
        001200700002        70        70        60        60        60        
        001200700003        85        85        85        60        85        
        001200700004        60        70        85        70        85        
        001200700005        70        60        60        60        85
```

data for String[][]predictiondata was:

```
 15        74.25        64.25        64.25        64.25        89.25        
 14        74.25        64.25        64.25        64.25        89.25
```

and for Means[] was:

```
String[]Means={"Means","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

so here's my code so far and the error output:

```
public void hashtree(String[][]dataset, String[][]predictiondata){
        //======fetch data from database then add 1 morre row for calculation

        String[]Means={"Means","0","0","0","0","0"};

        int heightofarray = (dataset.length)+(predictiondata.length)+(Means.length);
        int lengthofarray=(dataset[0].length);
        System.out.println("heightofarray: "+heightofarray+" lengthofarray: "+lengthofarray);
        String[][]toCalculate = new String[heightofarray][lengthofarray];


        for(int a=0;a<dataset.length;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<dataset[0].length;b++){
                toCalculate[a][b]=dataset[a][b];
            }
        }
        for(int a=0;a<predictiondata.length;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<predictiondata[0].length;b++){
                toCalculate[(dataset.length)+a][b]=predictiondata[a][b];
            }
        }
        for(int a=0;a<Means.length;a++){
            toCalculate[heightofarray-1][a]=Means[a];
        }


        System.out.println("should print String[][]toCalculate");
        for(int a=0;a<toCalculate.length;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<toCalculate[0].length;b++){
                System.out.print(toCalculate[a][b]+"\t");
            }System.out.println("");
        }
```

The order for the new combined array ( String[][]toCalculate ) is:

String[][]dataset

String[][]predictiondata

String[]Means

but however I always get the output

```
System.out.println("should print String[][]toCalculate");
    001200700001        70        70        70        55        70        
    001200700002        70        70        60        60        60        
    001200700003        85        85        85        60        85        
    001200700004        60        70        85        70        85        
    001200700005        70        60        60        60        85        
    15        74.25        64.25        64.25        64.25        89.25        
    14        74.25        64.25        64.25        64.25        89.25        
    null        null        null        null        null        null        
    null        null        null        null        null        null        
    null        null        null        null        null        null        
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    null        null        null        null        null        null        
    null        null        null        null        null        null        
    Means        0        0        0        0        0
```

Thank you very much for the solving

Answer (score 3):

```
int heightofarray = (dataset.length)+(predictiondata.length)+(Means.length);
```

This should be:

```
int heightofarray = (dataset.length)+(predictiondata.length)+(1);
```

The height of Means is 1

Comment: thank you very much, it works by changing the value of Means into this way of calculation.

Answer (score 1):

**It will probably be helpful for you to learn some debugging techniques, so you can solve problems like this when you see them in the future.**

To that end, here's one way to go about debugging:

Looking at the output, you can see that the `dataset` and the `predictiondata` are stored correctly.  It's the `Means` that are stored in the wrong place.

The `for` loop that stores the `Means` is different from the others.  The first two loops calculate the first available row in `toCalculate` by adding the number of rows that have already been populated.  But the last one counts backwards from the end.  That must be the problem.

The size of `toCalculate` is given by

```
  int heightofarray = (dataset.length)+(predictiondata.length)+(Means.length);
```

The `Means` are stored exactly `Means.length - 1` rows beyond the proper location.  That's because `heightofarray` is calculated incorrectly as the sum of the *height* of the `dataset` array, the *height* of the `predictiondata` array, and the ***length*** of the `Means`.

The correct calculation is

```
int heightofarray = dataset.length + predictiondata.length + 1;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you very much, it works by changing the value of Means into this way of calculation.